# Ruby: @@var or @var in Ruby modules?

Tags: ruby, variables, module

Is there a reason to not use @var or @@var in a Ruby module that is not destined to be used as a mixin in a class?  I've experimented and both variables results in the same behavior (simple module with basically a getter and setter for an @var or @@var).  I havent found an example or explanation that says a module can be used with some mutable state.  It almost seems to serve as a singleton in java.

I found a piece of code that used @@vars all over and it was never include/extend -ed in any other class so basically the developer was using the module to hold some state that may get updated but want all consumers of the module to see the same state at any given time and I suppose I could see some cases where this would be valuable, but since I've never seen any documented cases of this, I found it odd.

Regardless, is there any difference in an instance @var vs a 'class' @@var in the context of a module?

EDIT:

So I experimented a bit more. So my above question was assuming no usage of mixins.  This basically says that there is a class variable for all.....one instance of the module (again somewhat like a singleton) or you have an instance variable that is shared among all...one instance of the Module so using either for state results in the same behavior.  However, I made a instance method that's basically an instance getter to go along with my module method getter and did a mixin a class.  In the case of the @@var, the single module instance and all classes share the value it is set to.  With @var, the single 'module instance' had it's own value and then each class instance that sets @var for the mixin instance method had it's own @var.

I suppose this makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is any difference if the module is not included in a class. The differences between an instance variable of a class and a class variables are:

- Class variables are shared among the subclass. If `A` is a subclass of `B`, then `@@foo` of `A` is the same object as `@@foo` of `B`, but `@foo` of `A` is different from `@foo` of `B`.
- Class variables are shared among the class and all of its instances. If `a`, `b` are instances of `A`, then `@@foo` of `A` is the same object as `@@foo` of `a` and `@@foo` of `b`, but `@foo` of `A`, `@foo` of `a`, and `@foo` of `b` are diffferent.

Both of these are not relevant for modules that are not included in a class.

But since the use of a class variable may imply that there is such sharing between subclass and/or between a class and/or its instances, for clarity, it may be better to use an instance variable of a class rather than a class variable.

Comment: Downvoter, comment? I can't see nothing wrong with this answer.